# How do I project a point from [x,y] coordinates to LatLng in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet 1.0.0rc3 and need to use an absolute pixel value to modify something on my map.  Thus, I want to know where the user clicks in pixels, and then transform this back to `LatLng` coordinates.  I tried using `map.unproject()`, which seems like the correct method ([unproject() Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-unproject)).  But the LatLng  values that come out of that method are very different from the output of `e.latlng`.  (E.g., input `LatLng (52, -1.7)` and output `LatLng (84.9, -177)`).  So I must be doing something wrong.

**Question: What's the proper way to project points from layer (x,y) space to LatLng space?**

Here's a code snippet (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ehLr8ehk/)

```
// capture clicks with the map
map.on('click', function(e) {
  doStuff(e);
});

function doStuff(e) {
  console.log(e.latlng);
  // coordinates in tile space
  var x = e.layerPoint.x;
  var y = e.layerPoint.y;
  console.log([x, y]);

  // calculate point in xy space
  var pointXY = L.point(x, y);
  console.log("Point in x,y space: " + pointXY);

  // convert to lat/lng space
  var pointlatlng = map.unproject(pointXY);
  // why doesn't this match e.latlng?
  console.log("Point in lat,lng space: " + pointlatlng);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are just using a wrong method. To convert layer points to `LatLng` in Leaflet you need to use `map.layerPointToLatLng(point)` method.

So your code should look like this:

```
// map can capture clicks...
map.on('click', function(e) {
  doStuff(e);
});


function doStuff(e) {
  console.log(e.latlng);
  // coordinates in tile space
  var x = e.layerPoint.x;
  var y = e.layerPoint.y;
  console.log([x, y]);

  // calculate point in xy space
  var pointXY = L.point(x, y);
  console.log("Point in x,y space: " + pointXY);

  // convert to lat/lng space
  var pointlatlng = map.layerPointToLatLng(pointXY);
  // why doesn't this match e.latlng?
  console.log("Point in lat,lng space: " + pointlatlng);
}
```

And a changed [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mallack/ac95rn5o/).

Also you can check the [conversion methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-conversion-methods) that Leaflet offers for additional reference.

Comment: Thank you very much---this is exactly what I needed.  For my own notes and anyone else who reads this question, the `unproject` method transfers relative to CRS origin (which I think is the absolute origin of the map, rather than the view), while `layerPointToLatLng` transforms relative to the [origin pixel](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-getpixelorigin)  (see [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-conversion-methods)).