# Display Coordinates instead of Lat Long, when marker is dragged in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to display the x,y coordinates on 2 inputs when the marker is draged over the map. It is a non-geo map. Tiles are made were generated with gdal2tiles.py and positioned with rastercoords.js in leaflet.

For example, if i would drag the marker to the top right corner it should display the coordinates 4129x0.

Here is the link to the project: https://gamearena.ro/map/

My index.js

```
;(function(window) {
  // use below if you want to specify the path for leaflet's images
  //L.Icon.Default.imagePath = '@Url.Content("~/Content/img/leaflet")';

  function init (mapid) {
    var minZoom = 1
    var maxZoom = 5
    var img = [
      4129, // original width of image `karta.jpg`
      4608  // original height of image
    ]

    // create the map
    var map = L.map(mapid, {
      minZoom: minZoom,
      maxZoom: maxZoom
    })

    // assign map and image dimensions
    var rc = new L.RasterCoords(map, img)

    // set the view on a marker ...
    map.setView(rc.unproject([2065, 2304]), 4)

  var curLocation = [0, 0];
  // use below if you have a model
  // var curLocation = [@Model.Location.Latitude, @Model.Location.Longitude];

  if (curLocation[0] == 0 && curLocation[1] == 0) {
    curLocation = rc.unproject([2065, 2304]);
  }





    // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
    L.tileLayer('./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      noWrap: true,
      attribution:'<a href="gamearena.ro">GAME ARENA</a>'
    }).addTo(map)

map.attributionControl.setPrefix(false);

var marker = new L.marker(curLocation, {
    draggable: 'true'
  }).addTo(map);





marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
  document.getElementById('Latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
  document.getElementById('Longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
});

    



  }


  
  init('map')
}(window))
```

Thanks in advance!

I managed so far to display only the Latitude and Longitude when i drag the marker but being a map for a game i need to display the coordinates of the image in pixels. The "large" image is 4129x4608.

Comment: I think you mean the dimensions. Coordinates are latitude and Longitude and Dimensions are width and height. Please correct me here.

Comment: I searched for some answers and found the Geo Latitude and Longitude and Coordinates in leaflet are not the same. I need coordinates X,Y for the map which indid wil corespond with the dimensio of the image

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406683/6133426) might help you. What do you get if you do this after defining the `marker` variable, and before `marker.on('dragend',...)`?    `var pointXY = L.point(curLocation[0],curLocation[1]); console.log(pointXY); `